# Getting null instead of the boolean value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database that looks like this:

[image]

```
Query userQ = db.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
    userQ.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("DATASNAPSHOT", dataSnapshot.getValue()+"");
            Log.d("IF QUEST",dataSnapshot.child("ifQuestUser")+" "+dataSnapshot.getChildren());
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(dataSnapshot1.getKey(), dataSnapshot1.getValue()+"");
            }
            User user = new User(
                    dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class),
                    dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class),
                    dataSnapshot.child("lastName").getValue(String.class),
                    dataSnapshot.child("organization").getValue(String.class),
                    false
                    );
            dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Log.d("USER", user+"");
            if(user != null) {
                Log.d("IS QUEST USer", user.getName()+"  "+user.isIfQuestUser()+"");
                if(user.isIfQuestUser()) {
                    checkForQuestForumUser();
                } else {
                    checkForNonQuestForumUser();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Returns:

```
DATASNAPSHOT: {user15={name=Pranjal, lastName=Srivastava, email=pranjal.pranz@gmail.com, ifQuestUser=true, organization=Primus}}
```

On calling `datasnapshot.child('ifQuestUser');` it gives value

```
IF QUEST: DataSnapshot { key = ifQuestUser, value = null }
```

its value is showing `null` instead of `true`, and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get ifQuestUser

```
Query userQ = db.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
userQ.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Users user = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Users.Class);
            if(user.isIfQuestUser())
            {
            // ...
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I guess you have a model class `Users` having all the fields in firebase db, and have type of `ifQuestUser` as `Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your naming conventions of declaring keys first.

Secondly, don't use your key in your Model class. Use something like this `user.isQuestUser()` instead of `user.isIfQuestUser()` because firebase returns `null` in such cases. I was also getting the same kind of bug.